# Neo4J cypher or C# api array prop intersection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I Have relationships where there is a property on the relationship that is an array type. and I'm looking to get all relationships based on the array on the first rel, and then from then on, only find nodes connected where there is at least 1 common element. ie :

[a, b, c, d] ->(node)-[a, f, g]->     would link

but

[a,b,c,d]->(node)-[r,f,g]->           would not link

```
match (c:Company {RegistrationNumber : 'regNumber'}), c<-[r]-(n)
with n, c,r, extract(x in r.AlertIds | x) as alerts

match path= n-[*..7]-p
with c, n, path,extract(alertP in rels(path) | alertP.AlertId) as ap,  extract(a in alerts | a) as alert

return distinct n,alert,c,rels(path), ap, nodes(path)
```

The above cypher is looking a little crazy but basically I'm trying to get where any element in the array alerts (from the top part) is in any relationship found in the array in the rel on the second part.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**update 1**

http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ee23d3

above link is hopefully something that can be used to better understand what i'm looking for.

I want to able to be able to find all links following any path where there are common AlertIds.

so in the example linked I want to only see 1 path being returned with nodes (3,2,1,0) and the AlertIds that were found in the path ie ("e1")

If this would be easier to do to say any paths where the links are followed with the last node being the first company (the one in the initial match).

I hope this helps

Comment: Please clarify your data model and use case. Can you [share a console](http://console.neo4j.org/) with some representative sample data? Among the things to clarify: (1) are  `Company` nodes supposed to be part of the `path` used to generate the return data? (2) What happens if only part of a path satisfies the common-element test?: ignore the entire path, accept the entire path, accept the path up to the last "good" node, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=evwfed) that shows a query that may point you in the right direction. It is based on the same data as your console.

Here is the query it uses:

```
MATCH path=(company:Company {RegNumber : "3254"})-[emp:IsEmployee]->(employee:Person)-[rel*..7]->(company)
WHERE ALL (r IN rel 
           WHERE ANY (a IN r.AlertIds 
                      WHERE a IN emp.AlertIds))
RETURN company, emp.AlertIds AS alerts, employee, path
```

This query finds all paths up to length 8 that start and end with the same `Company` (3254), where the first relationship (`emp`) is of type `IsEmployee`, and where all subsequent relationships have at least one `AlertIds` element in common with the elements in `emp.AlertIds`.

Comment: thank you very much, this is the direction I was needing